# HTTPError: Response code 422 (Unprocessable Entity) on marking checkout as completed in shopify

Tags: node.js, shopify-app

I am new on Shopify app development with Shopify [node SDK](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node).

I am trying to mark a checkout as completed but getting error HTTPError: Response code 422 (Unprocessable Entity).

```
    { HTTPError: Response code 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
    at stream.catch.then.data (/workspace/upsell-node-express/node_modules/shopify-api-node/node_modules/got/index.js:386:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'HTTPError',
  host: undefined,
  hostname: 'xxxxxx.myshopify.com',
  method: 'POST',
  path:
   '/admin/checkouts/cee0406acf3ed1adb09cef798d2d44ac/complete.json',
  protocol: 'https:',
  url: undefined,
  statusCode: 422,
  statusMessage: 'Unprocessable Entity',
```

Checkout token : cee0406acf3ed1adb09cef798d2d44ac

I couldn't identify the issue why I am getting error code 422. According to the node SDK, the only token of checkout is required to mark as completed.